# Ducttape 0.3: Global variable assignment

Tags: ducttape

I'm having some issues with variable assignments in ducttape 0.3. I have a global variable block and I'd like one variable to refer to another bash-style. The `foo=$bar` assignment works correctly, but if I try to concatenate a string with a variable reference, the reference is ignored.

```
task do_it :: x=$bar f=$f {
    echo $x
    echo $f
}

global {
    foo="foo"
    bar=$foo
    cwd=/usr
    f="$cwd/bin"
}
```

Output:

```
foo
$cwd/bin
```

If I don't wrap the assignment to variable `f` in quotes, I get the following exception:

```
ducttape tmp.tape 
ducttape 0.3
by Jonathan Clark
ERROR: Illegal character in variable name. Adding a space after the variable name may fix this error.
/path/to/tmp.tape:10
    f=$cwd/bin
      ^
```

How can I do more clever variable assignments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation (e.g. "a $thing in a string") is not supported as the right-hand side of global variables and parameters in the outer ducttape workflow definition.

However, the imperative code blocks in each task are interpreted by bash and bash *does* support string interpolation. The solution is to move the part requiring string interpolation inside the task block:

```
task do_it :: x=$bar f=$f {
    f2="$f/bin"
    echo $x
    echo $f2
}

global {
    foo="foo"
    bar=$foo
    cwd=/usr
    f=$cwd
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is something I'm trying to do in a config file, since I'm defining a lot of filepaths that contain the same prefix -- and each config could have a variable number of files to process. For now I'll try a bash workaround.

Comment: Hm, could you start a new question about how to deal with filepaths that have the same prefix? A less minimal example to demonstrate how obnoxious it is may be helpful.

Comment: Another point is that it's a bit strange to pass files around as ducttape parameters. If you use "< inputFile" instead, you'll get extra niceties such as making sure all of your input files actually exist.